# Is playing Flash Videos on Freebsd still a problem, or is it ok now?

Tags: freebsd, flash

So am thinking about trying out Freebsd. But I heard stories that FreeBSD is really having problems with Flash, like it always crash, or it has to run through a linux emulator to get it to work ... bla bla bla...

My question therefore is: Can I install the latest Flash Plugin on FreeBSD with out any hitches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since August 2009 flash 10 works with out problems on FreeBSD. 
You can use either [linux-f10-flashplugin10](http://www.freshports.org/www/linux-f10-flashplugin10/) with f10 linuxulator or [linux-f8-flashplugin10](http://www.freshports.org/www/linux-f8-flashplugin10/) with f8.

After port instalation there is some black magic with nspluginwrapper and symlinks

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you install emulators/wine and use [winetricks](http://wiki.winehq.org/winetricks), you can easily load Firefox and Flash 10.  I've found performance of Firefox+flash in wine to be superior to linux firefox+flash on either FreeBSD or Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Use this howto and you will have Flash 10 working with **native browser** on FreeBSD:
http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=5786